# How to get the current active tab in a Flexdashboard document to reactively display different UI

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I am currently trying to make a Flexdashboard shiny app. I want to be able to display different UI in my sidebar given which tab is active in my output zone.

For this I considered using a `renderUI` and some basic conditions. But my problem is that I don't know how to get the active tab in flexdashboard. I have done some research but I wasn't able to find the info. I am not sure if we can add id to a tabset as in shiny and if it is possible, how to get the result corresponding to the id.

Here is some skeleton code of what I would like to do :

````
---
title: "Test"
runtime: shiny
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    vertical_layout: scroll
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
library(shiny)
library(flexdashboard)
})
```


# Page 1

## Input {.sidebar}

```{r}
radioButtons("radio", label = h3("Radio buttons"),
  choices = list("Choice 1" = 1, "Choice 2" = 2, "Choice 3" = 3), 
  selected = 1)


output$list1 <- renderUI({
  if (tab == "Tabs 1") {
    selectInput("select", label = h3("Select box"), 
      choices = list("Choice 1" = 1, "Choice 2" = 2, "Choice 3" = 3), 
      selected = 1)
  } 
  else {}
})

uiOutput("list1")
```

Column {.tabset }
-------------------------------------

### Tab 1

### Tab 2

### Tab 3
````

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that unlike in the `tabsetPanel(..., id = "xyz")` case where there is a `input$xyz` variable created, `Rmarkdown` does not show the same courtesy.

Hence, we need to hack that functionality ourselves with the help of a bit JavaScript:

```
---
title: "Test"
runtime: shiny
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    vertical_layout: scroll
---
<script>
$("body").on("shown.bs.tab", "a[data-toggle='tab']", function(e) {
   Shiny.setInputValue("active_tab", $(e.target).parent().index());
})
</script>
```

We are telling `shiny` that whenever a tab is shown, we want to set an input variable (i.e. something we can react upon on the `shiny` side) to the corresponding tab number (0 based).

We can then use `input$active_tab` to set our server logic:

```r
output$list1 <- renderUI({
   sel <- input$active_tab
   if (is.null(sel) || sel == 0) {
      selectInput("select", label = h3("Select box"),
                  choices = list("Choice A1", "Choice A2", "Choice A3"),
                  selected = 1)
   } else if (sel == 1) {
      selectInput("select", label = h3("Select box"),
                  choices = list("Choice B1", "Choice B2", "Choice B3"),
                  selected = 1)
   } else {
            selectInput("select", label = h3("Select box"),
                  choices = list("Choice C1", "Choice C2", "Choice C3"),
                  selected = 1)
   }
})
```

*Note.* I guess that there is a better event rather than `shown.bs.tab` to which you can attach the event handler. This may help to avoid testing for the `NULL` case in teh `render` part. This happens, because apparently `shown.bs.tab` does not fire when the first tab is shown by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working !
Do you know if it would be possible to adapt it to give different id to different `tabset` ?

Comment: I am not so deeply involved in `rmarkdown` so no idea. But with JS you can add `ids` if you like, why would you need different ids for the `tabsets`?

Comment: Ah ok, I am not a JS developer but I might consider learning it in the future for cases like this.
It was because in my main app, I have different pages (first row of tabs) and in the second page, I have three tabs (second row of tabs) and because of that, if I use your solution when I click on my second page, it consider that it should display the UI for the second tab even if it is in the first one. This is why I was considering adding id for each `tabsets`. But I worked around a different layout to use your solution so it is ok :)

Comment: Replace the `JS`  function body by `Shiny.setInputValue("active_tab", $(this).attr('id'));` in this way, the `active_tab`  will contain the `id` of the tab rather than the order.