# Assign an id to a specific tabset in flexdashboard (Shiny)

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

I would like to access the active tabset (not tab) in a flexdashboard for Shiny.

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64306794/how-to-get-the-current-active-tab-in-a-flexdashboard-document-to-reactively-disp) the answer providing the JS code creating an input variable with the tab id, but I would like to have it for a tabset.

My code looks like this:

```html
> TAB
> ==================
> 
> 
> ## Row {.tabset .tabset-fade}
> ---------------------
> 
> ### tabset A
> 
> ### tabset B
```

I would like to show programmatically either tabsetA or tabsetB. Any help is appreciated

I have no idea how to access it from JS